# Android browser still uses the old way of creating events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, events, dom-events

According to this [mozilla.org API guide on triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events),
**createEvent** and **initEvent** methods are deprecated
event objects **Event** or **CustomEvent** show be created in this fashion.

```
    var ev_name = 'test';
//  var ev = new Event(ev_name);
    var ev = document.createEvent("Event");
    ev.initEvent(ev_name, true, true);
```

However, this new method doesn't work on Android browser.
Are these two methods (createEvent and initEvent) really deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

This is true- The CustomEvent objects do not work in Android native browser.
A simple way to prove this is to go to this website on the android browser:
http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/custom-events/index.html

Test in Chrome (on Android) and it will work perfectly, as it is just the native Android browser that has issues.